# Links not working on Chrome & IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used jquery to bind menu on my website and that's working perfectly in Firefox but not on Chrome & IE.
**Issue** : When i click on link anchor text in chrome, no redirect or navigation.

**Check on website :** http://www.pricingindia.in

```
function show_n(e) {
        for (var t = 1; t < 9; t++) {
            if (e == t) {
                $("#snav" + t).css("display", "block");
                $("#stab" + t).addClass("act")
            } else {
                $("#snav" + t).css("display", "none");
                $("#stab" + t).removeClass("act")
            }
        }
        if (e == 1) {
$("#snav" + e).html('<ul class=\"snav\"><li><a href=\"http:\/\/www.pricingindia.in\/mobile\/87\" title=\"Mobile Phones\">Mobile Phones <span>(15707)<\/span><\/a><\/li><li><a href=\"http:\/\/www.pricingindia.in\/tablet\/24\" title=\"Tablets\">Tablets <span>(1394)<\/span><\/a><\/li><\/ul>');}
```

[image]

Comment: You're handling the `click` event for those objects. My guess is it's somewhere in your `widgets.js`. Because it's minified it is far too complex for anyone here to help you debug it. Perhaps if you provided the unminified version, we could be more helpful.

Comment: You can use this tool to unminify any javascript http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use append function

Try this

```
if (e == 1) {
    $('#snav' + e).append('<ul class="snav"><li><a href="http://www.pricingindia.in/mobile/87" title="Mobile Phones">Mobile Phones <span>(15707)</span></a></li><li><a href="http://www.pricingindia.in/tablet/24" title="Tablets">Tablets <span>(1394)</span></a></li></ul>');}
```

try this way

```
document.getElementById('#snav' + e).innerHTML = "<ul class="snav"><li><a href="http://www.pricingindia.in/mobile/87" title="Mobile Phones">Mobile Phones <span>(15707)</span></a></li><li><a href="http://www.pricingindia.in/tablet/24" title="Tablets">Tablets <span>(1394)</span></a></li></ul>";
```

Comment: Links is working now, but append function is appending same html 4-5 times(many times). How to force this to add only one time.

Comment: append is alternative of html function.

Comment: document.getElementById('#snav' + e).innerHTML = "<ul class="snav"><li><a href="http://www.pricingindia.in/mobile/87" title="Mobile Phones">Mobile Phones <span>(15707)</span></a></li><li><a href="http://www.pricingindia.in/tablet/24" title="Tablets">Tablets <span>(1394)</span></a></li></ul>";

Comment: Jay innerHtml no working. Can we force append function to append the html for one time only. Not serval times.

Comment: Resolved now, i was appending html on mouseover, which was adding the html several times. Now i changed that to on document ready.